# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics in libgdx

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, kotlin, build.gradle

in my libgdx gradle app I have a class of GroundHandler:

```
package com.mygdx.physics

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2

import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape

import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World

class GroundHandler(val world: World, val camera: OrthographicCamera) {
  private var groundBodyDef: BodyDef = BodyDef()
  private var groundBox: PolygonShape = PolygonShape()
  private var groundBody: Body? = null

  fun createGround() {
    groundBodyDef.position.set(Vector2(0f, 10f))
    groundBody = world.createBody(groundBodyDef)
    groundBox.setAsBox(camera.viewportWidth, 10.0f)
    groundBody?.createFixture(groundBox, 0.0f)
    groundBox.dispose()
  }
}
```

which is used in a different class. at first it compiles well, but when app window starts i get

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:133)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
        at com.mygdx.physics.GroundHandler.<init>(GroundHandler.kt)
        at com.mygdx.physics.Physics.createGround(Physics.kt:60)
        at com.mygdx.physics.Physics.create(Physics.kt:31)
```

Physics 31 is a line where I call createGround()

UPDATE:

build.gradle as requested  (without jar{} part that hasnt worked)

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'

  repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
      maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "physics game"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.1'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "kotlin"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"

    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "kotlin"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

all i did to this was changing 'java' to 'kotlin' two times and added kotlin dependency to buildscript {}

Comment: Did it help you?

Answer (score 4):

Just add jar{} section indo desktop.gradle like this:

```
apply plugin: "kotlin"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.your.class.name"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");

jar {
    manifest {}
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```